# How to install Kali?

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, grub, bios

Firstly, I tried to install Kali 2.0 from usb. Clicked install/graphicInstall. But it complained that there was no dvd disk with the packages in. Then, I went liveUSB and installed from there. I had Kali and Win8 on the disk. But grub didn't load. It just skipped to Windows. Then I tried to install Kali to another disk(SSD). But it just showed string 'Loading operating System...' and neither Grub, nor Kali started. 
By the way, I tried both EFI and non-EFI settings in BIOS.
So, how to install Kali successfully?
(I have kali persistence on one external disk and it works great!)

Comment: I would do it with non-EFI and beware must be in the root partition of the first disk.

Comment: So, I have to reintall kali in non-EFI and to set grub to the partition of '/', am I right?

Comment: yes, and grub to /dev/sda or in grub terminology  (hd0,0)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works. However it threw an error for grub on sda0, but sda1 fitted perfectly. Now grub can see even Windows!

Comment: because /dev/sda0 does not exists, it is /dev/sda for the entire disk or /dev/sda1 for the first partition. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do It with non-EFI, as it is more compatible and gives less problems with Linux instalations.

I also would install grub in the MBR of the disk, /dev/sda.

You installed it in /dev/sda1 and so much the better, because I can swear that way Windows updates/reinstallations won't mess up with it.

Comment: Really now two os are on different disks. But I think I will have to set systems to one disk ones. So, thank you again!